# How to do Excel-type formulas in MariaDB down a column?

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I have a MariaDB database where I've created a new column whose individual record values I'd like to populate with the results of multiplying the average of a previous column and the individual values from yet another column.  All such columns are from the same table in the same database.

Here is the code I proposed to MariaDB, but I got an "Invalid use of group function" error:

```
UPDATE myTable SET new_column = (AVG(col_1)) * col_2;
```

My goal is for the above code to be able to accomplish what the below Excel formula would accomplish if it were entered in the 'C' column in a typical Excel spreadsheet and populated down the length of the table:

```
=(AVG(A1:A7)*B1)
```

Are there any thoughts if this can be done in MariaDB?  All I found online was how to structure functions that return a single value to standard output, but not execute such a calculation down a column using an existing MariaDB function like 'AVG()' in the function.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0):

I *think* this is what you are describing:

```
UPDATE myTable t CROSS JOIN
       (SELECT AVG(col_1) as avg_col_1
        FROM t
       ) ta
    SET t.new_column = ta.avg_col_1 * col_2;
```